# Calling SOAP webservice using curl

Tags: linux, curl

I need to call a SOAP webservice using curl..
The service needs a username(user1) but does not need a password..When I execute the below, its asking for password and when I click ENTER it throws an "404" error. The same request passes successfully on SOAPUI tool.

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8" \
     -H "SOAPAction:" \
     -d @soap.csv \
     -X POST https://s.net/sotest/FileAttachmentService?wsdl \
     -u user1
```

Answer (score 0):

curl's -u parameter specifies the user/password for HTTP authentication.

All HTTP authentication schemes have a userid and a password, of some kind.

Your claim that you only need to provide a username suggests that username is really a parameter of your SOAP call, rather than used for HTTP authentication.

Another potential problem I can see is that SOAP is really just XML over HTTP, and most SOAP services typically use either `text/xml` or `application/xml` MIME content type, rather than `application/octet-stream`.

So, talk to whoever runs your SOAP service. Find out whether you are expected to use HTTP authentication or include a username parameter in your SOAP request, as well as the MIME type of your SOAP request.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the problem is related to the user/pass as you'd get a 403 (permision denied) and not a 404 (not found) in case there is something wrong with the authentication information. It must be related to the URL. Are you sure that the complete URL is correct? You should take the "?wsdl" out of the URL-path, because this points to the location of the WSDL and not to the Webservice endpoint.